# Outlook 2016: How to store an answer together with the original message

Tags: email, ms-office

In outlook for windows you can chose an implemented rule which stores an answer together with the original message in the same folder instead of the 'sent' folder.

Outlook for Mac doesn't have such a predefined rule. In outlook 2011 you could use an AppleScript for this purpose in the menu 'rules' which I did since outlook 2011 had been released.
Outlook 2016 doesn't provide such a solution.

My question is about how to store an answer together with the original message in the same folder in outlook 2016?

Comment: It's not a real answer unless there's no way to do this, but Outlook has a user voice forum where you ask for features and cote for them. Seems like this might just be waiting for the team to implement?

Comment: I did vote as I did for other missing functionalities in comparison to Office (Outlook) for windows. But nobody cares at Microsoft.